# vue.js - Increment global variable in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple for loop. I try to increment a variable on each cycle. It sounds like a very easy beginner task, but I struggle already for hours.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      globalVariable: 0,
      posts: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Post A' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Post B' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Post C' }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    incrementGlobalVariable() {
      return this.globalVariable++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
      <p>Global Variable @ {{ post.title }}: {{ incrementGlobalVariable() }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Global Variable: {{ globalVariable }}</p>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
Global Variable @ Post A: 303
Global Variable @ Post B: 304
Global Variable @ Post C: 305
Global Variable: 306
```

Error in console:

```
You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

(found in <Root>)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Global Variable @ Post A: 1
Global Variable @ Post B: 2
Global Variable @ Post C: 3
Global Variable: 3
```

Comment: As the error says, you have an infinite loop. The variable is incremented for the list items, which causes the component to rerender, which causes the loop to rerender, the variable is incremented again... Vue quits trying after the 300 times and gives a warning.

Comment: I don't understand why this triggers a rerender, can you explain? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'll post an answer, but it would help to know what you're actually trying to achieve. There is quite a possibly a better way.

Comment: Well, this is all I try to achieve.

Comment: I mean, why do you need a global variable that is then displayed at various values next to the list items?

Comment: I am loading posts dynamically from reddit. Each post is in a certain subreddit. A post can be in multiple subreddits. What I do is group them by their subreddit and then load them below each other. First comes the subreddit title, then the posts which are in that subreddit. I want to show a special advertisement block after 3 posts, therefor I need a global posts counter variable to find out when I need to show the advertisement block.

Comment: Why not check the current index of the `v-for`? Or do you not have that in your real code?

Comment: In the real code there are two v-for loops. One runs through all subreddits and the other one runs through the single posts from that subreddit, so I can't use the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `globalVariable` from data function, which is reactive and trigger rerender:

```js
let globalVariable = 0
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Post A' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Post B' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Post C' }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getGlobalVariable() {
      return globalVariable
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementGlobalVariable() {
      globalVariable++;
      return globalVariable
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
      <p>Global Variable @ {{ post.title }}: {{ incrementGlobalVariable() }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Global Variable: {{ getGlobalVariable }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole design pattern doesn't make sense because any updates to the list will increment the global again. So that means that your list is rather static.

If your list is static use `v-once`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      globalVariable: 0,
      posts: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Post A' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Post B' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Post C' }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    incrementGlobalVariable() {
      return ++this.globalVariable;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-once v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
      <p>Global Variable @ {{ post.title }}: {{ incrementGlobalVariable() }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Global Variable: {{ globalVariable }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
methods: {
incrementGlobalVariable() {
    this.globalVariable+=1;
    return this.globalVariable;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
      <p>Global Variable @ {{ post.title }}: {{ incrementGlobalVariable() }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Global Variable: {{ globalVariable }}</p>
</div>
```

Result:

```
Global Variable @ Post A: 1
Global Variable @ Post B: 2
Global Variable @ Post C: 3
Global Variable: 3
```

Comment: This is not the expected output. Pls check again.

Comment: Does not work, I get another output than you.